# C - Looping through an array of pointers

Tags: c

When I try to loop through the following C program, I get the error: "Segmentation fault: 11"

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

int i;

char *a[] = {
    "hello",
    "how are you",
    "what is your name"
};

for (i = 0; a[i][0] != '\0'; i++ ) {
    printf("\n%s", a[i]);
}
}
```

But when I replace the test in the `for` loop with the following, then I don't get an error and everything works fine.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    printf("\n%s", a[i]);
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain to me why the test `a[i][0] != '\0'` doesn't work, and what I should be doing instead.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) { ...}` :: there is no sentinel.

Comment: I think everyone else has it, but I'll just add in that the memory after your array isn't defined.  It's actually possible (1/256 times if you actually have the memory after the array) that your code WOULD work.  It's just completely undefined.  Arrays in C don't have a size built-in.  You have to track the size in parallel with your array, which is why your < 3 check works.  Or, with sizeof, you have to track the type.  When you pass the array to a function, it is turned into a pointer, and you lose the sizeof, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a terminating string that is missing.  Your definition for `a` should be

```
char *a[] = {
        "hello",
        "how are you",
        "what is your name",
        ""
    };
```

Without the empty string, you are accessing `a[3]` that does not exist and hence, the seg fault.

Comment: You've answered his question but I have an aside: would using `sizeof` be a way to determine termination without needing the extra string? (On second thought it might be ugly pointer arithmetic)

Comment: @nonsensical: You can use `sizeof` operator but you will have to use `sizeof ( a ) / sizeof ( char * )`.  In any event, the OP asked the reason for segfault and it was evident from his question that he is trying to terminate the loop on a NULL character that was missing.

Comment: @unxnut I agree, I was off topic. I was coding something similar at the time so my though process digressed.